# Python socket.send not working

Tags: python, sockets

Simple client - server app.

```
#Server use decode
import socket


s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)

while True:

    c,addr = s.accept()
    print("Got connection from " + str(addr))
    ret_val = s.send("Thank you".encode('utf-8'))
    print ("ret_val={}".format(ret_val))
    c.close()
```

Client:

```
#client use decode
from socket import gethostname, socket

serSocket = socket()
server = gethostname()
port = 12345
serSocket.connect((server, port))

data = serSocket.recv(1024)
msg = data.decode('utf-8')
print("Returned Msg from server:  <{}>".format(msg))

serSocket.close()
```

when the server tries to send the following exception occurred

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Got connection from ('192.168.177.1', 49755)
  File "C:/Users/Oren/PycharmProjects/CientServer/ServerSide/Server2.py", line 16, in <module>
    ret_val = s.send("Thank you".encode('utf-8'))
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As can be seen the client connects the server successfully.
But send fails.

What is the problem?

Comment: Firewall settings?

Comment: .encode('utf-8')) why you add that ? you should simply write s.send("Thnaks you") and check your Proxy or Firewall If They Dont Accept the COnnection

Comment: @SkillerDz. I encode because a TypeError exception is raised. `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` , which I also found in many posts. does this work for u without encoding? Regarding the firewall, I have win 10 and use windows defender firewall. What exactly should i check? I also do not understand, once the connection is established, as in this case, isn't fair to say the firewall is not a problem?

Comment: @Mika72 Please see my question above regarding the firewall.

Comment: @OJNSim and that is a probleme : serSocket = socket() , use serSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) for a better connection try it for see

Comment: @SkillerDz I fixed the socket instantiation in the client to socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM). Although these are the defaults (as in the server code). However, it didn't help. same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending on the *listening* socket, not on the connected socket. `connect` returns a new socket which is the one you must use for data transfer. The listening socket can never be used for sending or receiving data.

Change the send to this and your program will work fine:

```
ret_val = c.send("Thank you".encode('utf-8'))
```

(Note `c.send`, not `s.send`)